# as3 How can i change a number with two button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I need to change a number (dynamic text) with two button, - and +. If you press + (plus) on dynamic text must to add 1 and so on.

for ex:

```
text = i

on (release) {

    text =i+1;

}
```

Comment: Your sample is ActionScript 2, not 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, your code is in ActionScript 2, you should learn ActionScript 3.

Anyway, first create two `Buttons` and one dynamic `TextField`. Name them `btn_minus`, `btn_plus`, `tf` and write 0 in `TextField`.

and try this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

btn_minus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMinus);
btn_plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlus);

var count:int = 0;
function onMinus(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    count --;
    tf.text = String(count); 
}

function onPlus(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    count ++;
    tf.text = String(count);
}
```